# Access 2007 VBA Error 2467 for function

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error

Having a very weird problem. I have a function which is called when a form field gets focus. The function is passed four arguments, three of which are values from form fields and the fourth is a global variable which is set when the form loads. The function uses these variables to calculate the value for the field which called the function. This function is called in two different places. Everything was working fine, and now suddenly the function works when called from one place and doesn't work from the other, generating a 2467 run-time error, 'The expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exists'. I've checked that the values of the arguments being passed are correct, the function exists OK, so can't see why I'm getting this error. Anyone any ideas?

```
Private Sub cboFinalStage_GotFocus()
  'lookup stage based on TNM values
  cboFinalStage = FindStage(cboFinalStageT, cboFinalStageN, cboFinalStageM, gblCancer)
End Sub


Public Function FindStage(cboT As ComboBox, cboN As ComboBox, cboM As ComboBox,  
  strCancer As String) As String
  'use the TNM values entered to find the correct stage for the site and return it
  'error handling
  If gcfHandleErrors Then On Error GoTo PROC_ERR

  'declare variables
  Dim strTemp As String
  Dim strTable As String
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Dim strQuery As String
  Dim strSite As String
  Dim strSiteFull As String
  Dim strT As String
  Dim strN As String
  Dim strM As String

  'initialise variables - if there are no values entered in the 3 comboboxes, exit 
  'load tumour first in case it isn't already loaded
  Forms!frmContainer.subTumour.SourceObject = "fsubTumour"
  If Not IsNull(Forms!frmContainer.subTumour.Form!txtICD10) Then
    strSite = Left(Forms!frmContainer.subTumour.Form!txtICD10, 3)
    strSiteFull = Forms!frmContainer.subTumour.Form!txtICD10
  End If
  If Not IsNull(cboT.Value) Then
    strT = cboT.Value
    Debug.Print "T is " & strT
  End If
  If Not IsNull(cboN.Value) Then
    strN = cboN.Value
    Debug.Print "N is " & strN
  End If
  If Not IsNull(cboM.Value) Then
    strM = cboM.Value
    Debug.Print "M is " & strM
  End If
  If (IsNull(strT) Or IsNull(strN) Or IsNull(strM)) Then
    Debug.Print "null so exiting"
    Exit Function
  End If

  'identify the correct AJCC lookup table by cancer site
  Select Case [strCancer]
    Case "bla"
        strTable = "lkp_AJCC_bladder"
    Case "bre"
        strTable = "lkp_AJCC_breast"
    ...
  End Select
  Debug.Print "AJCC table is " & strTable

  'query the AJCC lookup table for the stage
  strQuery = "SELECT c_stage FROM " & strTable & " WHERE (((t_value)='" & strT & "')
   AND ((n_value)='" & strN & "') AND ((m_value)='" & strM & "'))"
  Debug.Print "query is " & strQuery
  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strQuery)
  If Not rs.EOF Then
    strTemp = rs.Fields(0).Value
    Debug.Print "result is " & strTemp
  End If
  rs.Close
  db.Close

  'return stage
  FindStage = strTemp

'error handling
PROC_EXIT:
  Exit Function
PROC_ERR:
  If (Err.Number = 2467) Then
    MsgBox "Unable to evaluate the stage", vbOKOnly, "Processing error"
    Resume PROC_EXIT
  Else
    MsgBox "Error: (" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume PROC_EXIT
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Try running in break-mode to see which line causes the error, if that doesn't make it clearer then please post the full code indicating the error line and we can take a look.

Comment: @MattDonnan: It doesn't even make it into the function, Matt. It hits the run-time error at the function call. I've edited to include the full code. What's so confusing is that the same call works perfectly from another subform but no longer works from this one.

Comment: Are you sure that **cboFinalStageT, cboFinalStageN, cboFinalStageM, gblCancer** are all been passed to the function, as they are all mandatory, the function should only fail at first instance if one of these is missing otherwise you should be able to enter break-mode, is glbCancer definately a **global** variable? Ps, Cancer & Tumor make for some pretty glum code reading ^_^

Comment: I put in some Debug.Print statements immediately before the call to check the values of all arguments, and they all printed correctly, so the values of the comboboxes on the form and of the global variable are fine. Global variable declared as Public and set on open, and no problems there. It's a cancer registration database, so apologies for the glumness!

Comment: Try amending the declarations from **cboT As ComboBox, cboN As ComboBox, cboM As ComboBox** to **cboT As Variant, cboN As Variant, cboM As Variant** just incase it is confusing itself with the values been passed, **Variant** is an open dynamic format which can cater for any value. It also looks like you are passing the combobox references and then the function is picking the values, it's much cleaner to pass the values straight into the function in the firstplace.

Comment: Didn't make any difference, still falls at the function call.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18408/discussion-between-matt-donnan-and-chelle)

Comment: I got the same error. Maybe it has something to do with the renaming of a subform